# Escaping the "@" in Razor

Tags: razor

I have the `i` incrementer variable in scope in a cshtml file. I'm trying to append it to an id of a span element. Is there any way to escape the "@i" such that the id renders as eg: IsSubscribedLabel1?

```
  <span id="IsSubscribedLabel@i">Label Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this syntax:

```
<span id="IsSubscribedLabel@(i)">Label Text</span>
```

Comment: It should have worked exactly as typed in the question.  Please post the undesired output that you were getting.

Comment: undesired output was "IsSubscribedLabel@i"